# I want to define the time that this function will appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I don't know how to set the function time. I'm using Angular.

`assinarApenasDespacho() { let configDialog: configDataModalDialog = { titulo: "Atenção", mensagem: "Tem certeza que deseja que deseja assinar este despacho?", labelBotao1: "Não", labelBotao2: "Sim", }`

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
setTimeout(function , milliseconds)

seeTimeout (() => {
   console.log('hello word')
}, 1000)
```